# AutoCompleteTextView com sugestões, a partir de um web service

Tags: java, android, textview

Tenho um AutoCompleteTextView que a partir de uma api em php retorna sugestões ao usuário baseado em valores contidos no meu banco de dados.

autocomplete.php:

```
include_once('../includes/config.php');
    $connection = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database;charset=utf8", $user, $pass);
      $sql = 'SELECT * from tbl_estoque';
      $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
      $statement->execute();
      if($statement->rowCount())
      {
            $row_all = $statement->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            header('Content-type: application/json');
            echo json_encode($row_all);

      }  
      elseif(!$statement->rowCount())
      {
          echo "no rows";
      }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quero que ao selecionar a sugestão o EditText referente ao preço seja preenchido também com base na coluna preço do meu banco de dados.

FragmentoPedidos.java

```
 private void AddProdutoDialog(){

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
    View subView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_adc_produto, null);
    new AutoCompletar(getActivity(), subView).execute();
    ...

private class AutoCompletar extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    private String result;
    private Context mContext;
    private View rootView;
    ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());

    public AutoCompletar(Context context, View rootView){
        this.mContext=context;
        this.rootView=rootView;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        //this method will be running on UI thread
        pdLoading.setMessage("\tAguarde...");
        pdLoading.setCancelable(false);
        pdLoading.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        result = null;
        PutUtility put = new PutUtility();
        try {
            result = put.postData(ADMIN_PANEL_URL + "public/autocomplete-app.php");

           /* put.setParam("UserId", params[0].toString());
            put.setParam("Latitude", params[1].toString());
            put.setParam("Longitude", params[2].toString());
            put.setParam("DateTime", params[3].toString()); */

            Log.v("result", result);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //this method will be running on UI thread
        //ArrayList<String> dataList = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> dataList=new ArrayList<>();
        pdLoading.dismiss();


        if(result.equals("no rows")) {

            // Do some action if no data from database

        }else{

            try {

                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

                // Extract data from json and store into ArrayList
                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    dataList.add(json_data.getString("produto_nome"));
                }

                final AutoCompleteTextView text = (AutoCompleteTextView)
                        rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvProduto_Nome);

                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                        (mContext.getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, dataList);

                dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                text.setThreshold(1);
                text.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // You to understand what actually error is and handle it appropriately
                DynamicToast.makeError(getActivity(),"Não foi possível contatar o servidor.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Como foi visto os resultados são obtidos pela classe "autocompletar". Eu só quero que o nome do produto receba sugestões mas quero que o preço referente ao produto selecionado seja preenchido também.

Aqui um exemplo de como eu quero que funcione:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi o problema adicionando um evento de click no dropdown do spinner, e um HashMap.

No ArrayList contém apenas o nome do produto e no HashMap contém o nome e o preço, então é buscado no HashMap o valor (preço) que corresponde a chave (produto) clicada. Segue o código da classe AutoCompletar atualizado:

```
private class AutoCompletar extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    private String result;
    private Context mContext;
    private View rootView;
    ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());

    public AutoCompletar(Context context, View rootView){
        this.mContext=context;
        this.rootView=rootView;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        //this method will be running on UI thread
        pdLoading.setMessage("\tAguarde...");
        pdLoading.setCancelable(false);
        pdLoading.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        result = null;
        PutUtility put = new PutUtility();
        try {
            result = put.postData(ADMIN_PANEL_URL + "public/autocomplete-app.php");

            Log.v("result", result);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        List<String> dataList=new ArrayList<>();
        final HashMap <String, String> produtosMap = new HashMap<>();
        pdLoading.dismiss();



        if(result.equals("no rows")) {

            // Do some action if no data from database

        }else{

            try {

                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

                // Extract data from json and store into ArrayList
                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    //dataList.add(json_data.getString("produto_nome"));
                    produtosMap.put(json_data.getString("produto_nome"), json_data.getString("produto_preco"));
                    dataList.add(json_data.getString("produto_nome"));
                }

                final AutoCompleteTextView text = (AutoCompleteTextView)
                        rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvProduto_Nome);

                final EditText preco = (EditText)
                        rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvProduto_Preco);


                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                        (mContext.getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, dataList);

                dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                text.setThreshold(1);
                text.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

                text.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        String produto = (String) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
                        String preco_produto = produtosMap.get(produto);
                        preco.setText(preco_produto);
                    }
                });

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // You to understand what actually error is and handle it appropriately
                DynamicToast.makeError(getActivity(),"Não foi possível contatar o servidor.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

    }

}
```